# Flutter Extension and Stateful Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am working on a Stateful Widget in Flutter and its part of an extension.
The problem I am having is that the value I pass into my Stateful widget is getting overwritten because I need to set my value to something to make Flutter happy.

My Stateful Widget first takes in data like this:

```
class TranslateOnHoverRight extends StatefulWidget {
final Widget child;
final double movement;
TranslateOnHoverRight({Key key, this.child,this.movement}) : super(key: key);

@override
_TranslateOnHoverRightState createState() => _TranslateOnHoverRightState();
}
```

It takes a widget and a dobule.

Then I have the _TranslateOnHoverRightState class that looks like this, and here where I don't get everything right.

```
class _TranslateOnHoverRightState extends State<TranslateOnHoverRight> {

final nonHoverTransform = Matrix4.identity();
final hoverTransform = Matrix4.identity()..translate(_movement, 0, 0);

bool _hovering = false;
static double _movement = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
        onEnter: (e) => _mouseEnter(true,widget.movement),
        onExit: (e) => _mouseEnter(false,0),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
           duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
           child: widget.child,
           transform: _hovering ? hoverTransform : nonHoverTransform,
        ),
     );
}

void _mouseEnter(bool hovering,double move) {
    setState(() {
        _hovering = hovering;
        _movement = move;
    });
  }
}
```

At the top, I am passing in `_movement` to my `hoverTransform` variable and I am setting it to zero.

Now in my `Widget build` function I return a MouseRegion which has the `onEnter` set to use my function `_mouseEnter` that is taking parameters boolean and a double from the widgets in parameter `widget.movement`. The idea here is that now when hovering over with mouse pointer movement should happen but nothing happens.

In my `_mouseEnter` function I pass in true or false and the value sent from widget and passing it to my `_movement` variable like so:

```
void _mouseEnter(bool hovering,double move) {
    setState(() {
        _hovering = hovering;
        _movement = move;
    });
}
```

And at the end everything is used in as a extension like this:

```
Widget mouseRightOnHover(double moveIt) {
    return TranslateOnHoverRight(
        child: this,
        movement: moveIt,
    );
}
```